# How to reload a datable after adding a data through ajax?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

I've a UI which adds data to the database via ajax. That data should reflect in my datatable without reloading the whole page or by just reloading the datatable. I've tried using `t.api().ajax.reload()` & `t.ajax.reload()` but it throws error in console like "*Cannot read property 'reload' of undefined*" or "*t.api is not a function*" i Don't know what am doing wrong here. Below are some reference

**UI - Adding datas through add role btn which brings a pop up**

[image]

**Add Role Pop Up**

[image]

**HTML**

```
    <div id="roles" style="display: block" >   
                <ul class="tab-onebtn">
                    <li class="logouttab"> <a  style="float: left;" id="myBtn"> Add Role </a> </li>
                </ul>  

                <div class="table roles_table" >
                    <table class="example display" id="mytable" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
                       <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>Roles</th>
                            <th>Action</th>
                        </tr>
                       </thead> 
                       <tbody>
                  <?php foreach($resultRoles as $r) { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td><?php echo $r->cptv_role; ?></td>
                            <td></td>  
                        </tr>
                  <?php } ?>     
                       </tbody>
                    </table>  
                </div>



              <h1> Roles coming soon</h1>

              </div>

<div id="myModal" class="modal" >

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
      <span class="close">×</span>

<!--  <div class="modal-header">
    <h2 style="text-align:center";>Add Role</h2>
  </div>-->
  <div class="modal-body">

    <form action="" method="post" class="addRoleForm">
           <?php if(!empty($this->session->flashdata('error')) ) {  ?><div class='error' style="margin-top: -20px;"><h2><?php echo $this->session->flashdata('error');  ?> </h2></div><?php } ?>
           <?php if(validation_errors() != false) {  ?><div class='error'><?php echo validation_errors(); ?></div><?php } ?>
            <div class="field-wrap">

            <label>
              Role <span class="req">*</span>
            </label>
            <input name="role" class="roleInput" type="text"required autocomplete="off"/>

          </div>

           <div id="result" class="msg" style="display:none;"></div>

          <button class="button button-block submitbtn"/><span class="addRole" >Add Role </span> <span class="Added" style="display:none;"><b>Successfully Added </b></span></button>

    </form>


  </div>
<!--  <div class="modal-footer">
    <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
  </div>-->
</div>

</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
// Ajax post
$(document).ready(function() {
  var  t = $('#mytable').DataTable();
$(".addRoleForm").submit(function(){  
event.preventDefault();
var str = $(this).serialize(); 
console.log();
jQuery.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: base_url+ "admin/roles/addRole",
dataType: 'json',
data: str,
success: function(result) {
if (result)
{
   console.log(result);
// Show Entered Value
jQuery("div#result").show();
if(result.success){
//    $('#mytable tbody').append('<tr><td>'+$('input[name="role"]').val().trim()+'</td><td></td></tr>');
//    $('#mytable').DataTable();
t.api().ajax.reload();
jQuery("div.msg").html("<div class='success'><h2>"+result.success+"</div>");
setTimeout(function(){
    span.click();
    }, 2000);

}else{
   jQuery("div.msg").html("<div class='error'><h2>"+result.error+"</h2></div>"); 
}
//var ref = $('#mytable').DataTable(); 
//setInterval( function () {
//    ref.ajax.reload(); // user paging is not reset on reload
//}, 1000 );

 setTimeout(function(){
  jQuery("div#result").hide();
  $(".roleInput").val('');

 }, 2000);

}
}
});
});
});
```

**Controller**

```
public function addRole() {

         if (empty($this->sessionData)){
//            print_r($this->sessionData['id']); exit;
            $this->index();
        }


        $post = $this->input->post();
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('role', 'Role', 'trim|required|xss_clean');
        if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
            $roleDet = $this->roles_model->checkCpRoles(array('cptv_role' => $post['role']));
            if ($roleDet->num_rows()) {
                $data['error'] = " Role already Exist.";
                echo json_encode($data);
            } else {
                $result = $this->roles_model->addCpRoles(array('cptv_role' => $post['role']));
                if ($result){
                $data['success'] = " Successfully added the Role ";
                echo json_encode($data);
                } else {
                    $data['error'] = " Something went wrong ";
                echo json_encode($data);
                }

            }

        }



    }
```

**Can somebody help me please!?**

Answer (score 0):

Reload the datatable after ajax success like:

You're using old API: $().dataTable() (v1.9 and earlier) which is still available in DataTables v1.10. The old API returns jQuery object, so you should use .api() in order to use DataTable API methods:

```
oTable.api().ajax.reload();
// where oTable is the reference to datatable.
```

Comment: Am getting this error "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'reload' of undefined"

Answer (score 0):

Since you have written some code in php I dont understand it much, But I can point the issue in your code. You are having a `normal HTML table to which you apply the DataTable plugin`.

Your code `t.api().ajax.reload();` breaks because the DataTable is not fetching data via ajax, meaning your DataTable is not setup for a ajax based data, **Its a normal HTML table**.

What I suggest you is return the entire row that you need to append into the table (`make sure all the columns are returned, right now you have only 2 columns in your table`) in your ajax success method. Now all you have to do is **add this new column into the dataTable and redraw the table**.

Syntax to add a new row into the dataTable and redraw it is as below.

```
t.row.add(yourArrayGoesHere).draw( false );
```

So that means your response from the server must be a array. Example : `["Admin",""]`

**Test:** Open your console window in the browser (press F12 to open)
and paste this code and hit enter.  You must be able to see a new row with first cell having the value Admin.

```
 t.row.add(["Admin",""]).draw( false );
```

Let me know if this helps.

Comment: in console i get a error like `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'add' of undefined(…)` for your test code.

Comment: your `t` must be a global variable to test in that way,  For testing purpose I would ask you to make your variable `t` as global, simply remove the keyword `var` infront of `t` to make it global

Answer (score 0):

This is the best example i have ever seen in which datatable is implemented with the Codeigniter framweork.

http://mbahcoding.com/tutorial/php/codeigniter/codeigniter-ajax-crud-using-bootstrap-modals-and-datatable.html